# Office 365/ onedrive for business - sharing the same folder between 2 users

Tags: sync, onedrive, office365

I have 2 office 365 account (business) I want to sync one folder for 2 of them (the same folder should be on both computers, and in the cloud).

One drive is installed on both computer - but each computer sync to a different location

How can I sync one folder (it's a huge 4Gb folder) so it will be the same on both computers and the servers ?

SharePoint gives you something close to this but - the files are not stored locally and it looks like you need to upload each file separately...

Comment: I don't understand the question fully, when you sync a site or "folder" it will sync from the server and retain a local cached copy within the "SharePoint" folder in Windows Explorer. Could you please elaborate further?

Answer (score 0):

If you share the folder with both users, or from one to the other if it's in one of their OneDrives, both users can sync that folder from OneDrive. They can browse to it and either: 1) click 'sync', or 2) right-click on OneDrive in the system tray, select 'Sync new folder', and paste the URL of the folder there.